# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, sql, pdo

soy principiante y estoy tratando de guardar la ruta del directorio en la base de datos pero me sale un error que no eh podido resolver les comparto el codigo de antemano gracias.
ERROR
"Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined "

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$title = inputClear($_POST['title']);
$price = inputClear($_POST['price']);
$description = $_POST['description'];
$img = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
$images = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
$options = $_POST['options'];

$load_img = '../'.$realstate_config['folder_img'] . $_FILES['img']['name'];

move_uploaded_file($img, $load_img);


$statement = $conection->prepare('INSERT INTO houses (id, title, price, description, img, category_id) VALUES (null, :title, :price, :description, :img, :options)');

$statement->execute(array(
    ':title' => $title,
    ':price' => $price,
    ':description' => $description,
    ':img' => $_FILES['img']['name'],
    ':options' => $options
)); 

$last_id = $conection->lastInsertId();

$folder_name = '../'.$realstate_config['folder_img'] .$last_id.'/';
if(!empty($_FILES['images'])) {
    if(!file_exists($folder_name)) {
        mkdir($folder_name, 0777);
    }
    
    foreach($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'] as $key => $value) {
        if(file_exists($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key])) {
            move_uploaded_file($images[$key], $folder_name.$_FILES['images']['name'][$key]);
        }
    }
    
    $statement = $conection->prepare("UPDATE houses SET (folder_img) = ('.$folder_name.') WHERE id = $last_id");

    $statement->execute(array(
    ':images' => $_FILES['images']['name']*---------- AQUI MARCA EL ERROR ---------*/
    )); 
}
```

Ya intente con

```
$statement = $conection->prepare("UPDATE houses SET (folder_img) = ($folder_name) WHERE id = $last_id");

$statement->execute(array(
        ':images' => $_FILES['images']['name'],
        ':id' => $last_id
    ));
```

TAMBIEN agregando los dos puntos para indicar el placeholder

```
$statement = $conection->prepare("UPDATE houses SET (:folder_img) = ($folder_name) WHERE id = :$last_id");

$statement->execute(array(
        ':images' => $_FILES['images']['name'],
        ':id' => $last_id
    ));
```

Pero el error persiste

Comment: Tienes que hacer coincidir exactamente el marcador en la consulta con el del array en `execute()`. Observa bien la respuesta que te dieron, el array que va en execute tiene un elemento `':folder_img'=>$_FILES['images']['name']` y no `':images'=>...` como tu código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema ocurre porque en tu consulta `UPDATE` no pusiste marcador:

```
$statement = $conection->prepare("UPDATE houses SET (folder_img) = ('.$folder_name.') WHERE id = $last_id");
```

Intenta de este modo:

```
$statement = $conection->prepare("UPDATE houses SET folder_img = :folder_img WHERE id = :id");

$statement->execute(array(
':folder_img' => $_FILES['images']['name'],
':id'=>$last_id
));
```

He puesto un marcador también para el `id` del `WHERE`.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, ya lo intente pero el problema persiste de igual manera ya agrege los intentos a la pregunta tambien intente poner asi como muestras en la consulta sql :folder_img pero no me funciono gracias

Comment: @edwin edita la pregunta y pon cómo queda ahora el código corregido.

Comment: @edwin no lo pusiste como te dije, veo que lo tienes así: `WHERE id = :$last_id` pero no funciona así, el marcador debe tener el mismo nombre que pones en el array (`:id`), y no se usa `$` delante, tú estás usando `:$last_id`

Comment: Aun poniendolo asi -----
UPDATE houses SET folder_img = :folder_name WHERE id = :id---- continua el erro ya actualice la pregunta

Comment: Sigue estando mal. Por favor compara tu código con mi respuesta. Estás poniendo el marcador a la izquierda del `=` y debe ser a la derecha.

Comment: puse tu codigo exactamente y en efecto ese era el problema solo que me guardaba un array en la base de datos asi que lo hice asi y ya me funciono muchas gracias ------- $statement->execute(
        ':folder_img' => $folder_name, ----